# Powerbi DAX : creating calculated column that contains minimum values in the same row from multiple other columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

given columns with numerical values:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 |
| 8 | 5 |

I'd like to create a calculated column with the minimum value from each row:

| Column C |
| --- |
| -1 |
| 5 |

This seems like it would be fairly easy but I'm unable to do this

I was thinking just the minx function would work but it does not

Answer (score 0):

```
Column C = MIN('Table'[Column A], 'Table'[Column B])
```

[image]